# Probability of chosen urns being filled after randomly throwed 2 balls k times

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

We have *n* urns. Repeat next process *k* times: choose 2 distinct urns, throw ball into each. What is the probability of choosing **2 urns** with at least 1 ball in it?
(e.g. we have 8 urns. Then choose 3 times: (1, 2), (7, 4), (8, 2). So we have 2 balls in 2-nd urn and 1 ball in each of urns 1, 4, 7, 8.)

Probability of urn being with at least 1 ball after *k* trials: $P=1-(\frac{n-2}{n})^k$. If one chooses 2 urns independently: $P=(1-(\frac{n-2}{n})^k)^2$.
What will be the probability if one chooses 2 distinct urns at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that one iteration leaves both urns empty is

$$
\frac{\binom{n-2}2}{\binom n2}=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{n(n-1)}\;,
$$

so the probability of both urns being empty is

$$
\left(\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{n(n-1)}\right)^k\;.
$$

The probability of a particular one of the two urns being empty is

$$
\left(\frac{n-2}n\right)^k\;.
$$

Thus the probability of neither urn being empty is

$$
1-2\,\left(\frac{n-2}n\right)^k+\left(\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{n(n-1)}\right)^k\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot for understanding.